# Upgrade my rooted device to 5.1 Lollipop

Tags: updates, lenovo

I have a rooted [Lenovo A369i](http://www.gsmarena.com/lenovo_a369i-5850.php) phone. Now I want to upgrade it to 5.1 Lollipop, So What steps to follow to get Lollipop in my device ?

Comment: Can you give some more information about your query? like your recent android version, build number.

Answer (score 1):

Lenovo A369i device is not so famous and there seems to be no developer support for this phone..

It doesn't even have KitKat update I think..
There seems to be no CyanogenMod ROMs or even any other simple custom ROM.
The device is completely outdated and you are not going to have any update.

You're stuck with Jelly Bean 4.2.2 :(

Better get a new phone, or if you want Lollipop like UI (design), you can install Xposed (google to know how) and then install the module MonsterUI (Link: http://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/modules/mod-monsterui-theme-device-to-material-t3055569) to give your phone Lollipop-like look.